# Hashing within a GA

Tags: java, hash, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on a final year project, the idea of using a genetic algorithm in timetabling college classes.

Part of the algorithm is to test what violations the prospective timetables break. 1 of them is room clashes - a room being double booked.

Using java, I have overridden the default getHashcode  of my roomTimeSlot(combination of the room and a an id given to each time slot, i.e monday 9-10, moday 10-11 etc)to my own code 
I want to use this hashcode to map every assigned roomTimeslot for each lecture.

My question is how do I do this and how do I detect collisions?

Comment: You detect collisions by comparing the hash codes. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I know i havent explained well at all, how do I compare the codes? by putting them into a hashMap is it? I understand the theory behind it, just not how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

First i would loose the Hash idea...

Then you probably will create an Interval Object containing the start and end, that you are putting in your Collection.

You can easily implement a method on this Class that can detects a collision:

```
public boolean hasCollision(Interval inter){....}
```

Now before inserting you iterate over you collection and call the hasCollision() methods...

I you want to optimise the results, you can also make the Interval object implement Comparable and use a Sorted collection.

You can also look at [interval tree data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) for this, and add elements only if there is no collisions / intersections in the interval.